# An error occurred while processing the field Style : Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: acumatica

I want to achieve, is to get the QtyOnHand of a specific inventoryID in InSiteStatus table.

I created a DAC for InventoryID and labeled it as "Style" and another for QtyOnHand.

I used FieldUpdated event handler, so every time an user selects a new inventoryID it will update the QtyOnHand field.

Here's my work.

DAC:

```
    public class AllocationFilter: IBqlTable
    {
    #region Style
    public abstract class style : IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXInt]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Style")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryID)
    , typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD)
    , typeof(InventoryItem.descr)
    , SubstituteKey = typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD)
    )]
    public virtual int? Style { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region OnHand
    public abstract class onHand : IBqlField
    { }
    [PXDecimal()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "On Hand", Enabled = false)]

    public virtual decimal? OnHand { get; set; }
    #endregion
    }
```

Event Handler:

```
    protected void AllocationFilter_Style_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
    // Obtain the new data record that contains the updated
    // values of all data fields
    AllocationFilter filterAlloc = (AllocationFilter)e.Row;

    if (filterAlloc == null)
    return;

    // This is where the error triggers...
    PXResultset<INSiteStatus> insitestatus = PXSelect<INSiteStatus, 
    Where<INSiteStatus.inventoryID, 
    Equal<AllocationFilter.style>>>.Select(this);

    foreach (INSiteStatus sitestatus in insitestatus)
    {
        filterAlloc.OnHand = sitestatus.QtyOnHand;
    }
    }
```

I think there is a problem with my PXResultSet, can you help me guys?

Comment: I think you are just missing either a Current or Required on your PXSelect. Jeff's answer already has the view with the correct syntax. Just make sure you wrap your Style field in a current like this... Current<AllocationFilter.style>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options that I see here.

One, create a View for this

```
public PXSelect<INSiteStatus,Where<INSiteStatus.inventoryID,Equal<Current<AllocationFilter.style>>> StyleStatus;
```

Then in your event handler

```
foreach (INSiteStatus sitestatus in StyleStatus.Select())
{......}
```

Or two, inline like you have it

```
PXResultset<INSiteStatus> insitestatus = PXSelect<INSiteStatus, 
Where<INSiteStatus.inventoryID, 
Equal<Required<INSiteStatus.inventoryID>>>.Select(this,filterAlloc.Style);
```

Unless you need greater control of the select statement, I would use the View

Comment: I used your second option and changed <Required<INSiteStatus.inventoryID>> into <Required<AllocationFilter.style>> and it works. Thank you it helps me a lot.